# How to subtract these two binary numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My teacher told me this method for subtracting binary numbers: For example, I have to subtract: 100100-10111. Method is the following: invert zeros and ones in the second binary number and add it to the first binary number and add one also: 100100 + 011011 (inverted) + 1 = 101101. But the result of subtraction should be 01101 instead of 101101. What is the rule for not writing this last number one?

Comment: Your teacher missed a step - if you read Step 6 in Method 2 here then you will see the additional step is to discard the first digit of the answer (in your case, the 1): https://www.wikihow.com/Subtract-Binary-Numbers 
Step 7 explains why this works,, using base 10 numbers instead

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that if you add to the number $N$ the number $\bar N$, which is $N$ with every digit inverted, you will get the number consisting of all $1$s. If you add $1$ to this, you will get the power of 2. That's why you need to subtract the 1 on the corresponding place:

$$
10111_2+01000_2=11111_2=100000_2-1\\[5pt]
100100_2 -10111_2 = 100100_2 - (100000_2-01000_2-1) \\
= 100100_2 + 01000_2 + 1 -100000_2 = 101101_2 - 100000_2 = 1101_2
$$

You can use the same trick with decimal system if you want. In that case you need to “invert” digit by subtracting it from $9$:
$$
91203-6705 = 91203-(10000-3294-1) = 91203+3294+1-10000\\ = 94498-10000=84498
$$